# html not updating until the end of an ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to write a 3 second countdown function in JavaScript.  The start of the countdown is set by the server so I have setInterval function which calls an ajax function which runs a script on the server to see if it is ready to start the countdown.  If the countdown is set, the data returned is that the countdown is ready and will start in a specified number of milliseconds.

I've got the following function which, if I step through I can see the screen updating step by step.  However, when I simply run the script it updates everything in bulk.  I do not understand why?

```
        $.ajax({
            url : "/check_countdown/", // the endpoint
            type : "GET", // http method
            data : { info : info }, // data sent with the post request
            // handle a successful response
            success : function(json) {
                console.log(json);
                if (json.ready == 'True') {
                    // if we have a start_time then we get ready for the count down
                    console.log("Countdown ready to start!"); // sanity check
                    // stop pinging the server
                    clearInterval(countdownInterval);
                    // clear screen
                    $('#holdingImage').hide();
                    // show countdown block
                    $('#countdownText').show();
                    startTime = new Date().getTime() + json.milliseconds;
                    nowTime = new Date().getTime();
                    console.log("Every ", nowTime, startTime);
                    while (nowTime < startTime) {
                        nowTime = new Date().getTime();
                        }
                    $('#countdownText').html("<h1>Three</h1>");
                    startTime = startTime + 1000;
                    console.log("Second ", nowTime, startTime);
                    while (nowTime < startTime) {
                        nowTime = new Date().getTime();
                        }
                    $('#countdownText').html("<h1>Two</h1>");
                    startTime = startTime + 1000;
                    console.log("Counts ", nowTime, startTime);
                    while (nowTime < startTime) {
                        nowTime = new Date().getTime();
                        }
                    $('#countdownText').html("<h1>One</h1>");
                    } else {
                        console.log("Countdown NOT ready to start!"); // another sanity check
                        }
            },
            // handle a non-successful response
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                    " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
            }
        });
```

I figure a second (1000 milliseconds) between updates should be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I came up with.  I'm not convinced by its efficacy but ...

I changed the success function to:

```
            success : function(json) {
                console.log(json);
                if (json.ready == 'True') {
                    // if we have a start_time then we get ready for the count down
                    console.log("Countdown ready to start!"); // sanity check
                    console.log(json);
                    // stop pinging the server
                    clearInterval(countdownInterval);
                    // clear screen
                    $('#holdingImage').hide();
                    // show countdown block
                    $('#countdownText').show();
                    startTime = new Date().getTime() + json.milliseconds;
                    nowTime = new Date().getTime();

                    while (nowTime < startTime) {
                        nowTime = new Date().getTime();
                        }
                    startCountdown();
                    }
```

I added a new function called `startCountdown()` which is:

```
    function startCountdown () {
        var display1 = document.querySelector('#countdownText'),
            startTime = 5,
            remainingTime = startTime,
            timer = new CountDownTimer(startTime);

        timer.onTick(format1).start();

        function format1(minutes, seconds) {
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display1.textContent = seconds;

            remainingTime = parseInt(minutes) * 60 + parseInt(seconds);

            if ((minutes=="00") && (seconds=="00")){
                console.log("time expired!");  // sanity check
            }

        }
    }
```

And then I used this timer.js script which I had from elsewhere (I do not know where I got it so cannot credit the author - sorry)

```
function CountDownTimer(duration, granularity) {
  this.duration = duration;
  this.granularity = granularity || 1000;
  this.tickFtns = [];
  this.running = false;
}

CountDownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
  if (this.running) {
    return;
  }
  this.running = true;
  var start = Date.now(),
      that = this,
      diff, obj;

  (function timer() {
    diff = that.duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    if (diff > 0) {
      setTimeout(timer, that.granularity);
    } else {
      diff = 0;
      that.running = false;
    }

    obj = CountDownTimer.parse(diff);
    that.tickFtns.forEach(function(ftn) {
      ftn.call(this, obj.minutes, obj.seconds);
    }, that);
  }());
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.onTick = function(ftn) {
  if (typeof ftn === 'function') {
    this.tickFtns.push(ftn);
  }
  return this;
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.expired = function() {
  return !this.running;
};

CountDownTimer.parse = function(seconds) {
  return {
    'minutes': (seconds / 60) | 0,
    'seconds': (seconds % 60) | 0
  };
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.stop = function() {
  this.running = false;
};
```

All in, it gives me my desired result

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
        url : "/check_countdown/", // the endpoint
        type : "GET", // http method
        data : { info : info }, // data sent with the post request
        async: false, //<---- Add this
        ....
```

only Add (async: false)

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work but I think you're on the right lines.  From the reading I've been doing I think I need to do the countdown outside the ajax function, perhaps by initiating it through a changed variable set within the ajax.

Comment: Yes, do it outside the ajax function by [ return  ]

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand